# google guava with GWT when performing pattern search and range search on collections2

Tags: java, gwt, collections, guava

I want to perform search operations on Google Gauva collections in the GWT application.
Those are working correctly in standalone application.But in GWT they are producing 
runtime problems.I'm showing my sample code of onModuleLoad() of EntryPoint class.
Iset the buildpath for both guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar and guava-10.0.jar

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    List<String> sList=new ArrayList<String>();
    sList.add("arun kumar");
    sList.add("ashok kumar");
    sList.add("ravi kumar");
    sList.add("kiran kumar");
    sList.add("rama");
    sList.add("ram");
    sList.add("rama krishna");
    sList.add("phani");
    sList.add("vikram");
    sList.add("veeru");
    sList.add("arjun");
    sList.add("naresh");


    //pattern matching
    Collection<String> filterdNamesKumar=Collections2.filter(sList, Predicates.containsPattern("kumar"));
    //starts with
    Collection<String> filterdNamesRam=Collections2.filter(sList, Predicates.containsPattern("^ram"));
    Collection<String> filterdNamesAr=Collections2.filter(sList, Predicates.containsPattern("^ar"));

    System.out.println(filterdNamesAr.toString());
    System.out.println(filterdNamesKumar.toString());
    System.out.println(filterdNamesRam.toString());

    Map<String,String> emps=new HashMap<String,String>();
    emps.put("emp1","01/02/2013");
    emps.put("emp2", "10/12/2013");
    emps.put("emp3","20/11/2013");
    emps.put("emp4", "25/09/2013");
    emps.put("emp5", "15/12/2013");
    emps.put("emp6", "20/08/2013");
    emps.put("emp7", "02/02/2012");

    for(String s:emps.keySet()){
        String strDate=emps.get(s);
        DateTimeFormat dateFormat=DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date empDate=dateFormat.parse(strDate);



            Date startDate=dateFormat.parse("01/11/2013");
            Date endDate=dateFormat.parse("31/12/2013");
            Range<Date> range=Ranges.closed(startDate, endDate);
            boolean b=range.apply(empDate);
            if(b){
                Window.alert("date found between boundaries");
            }

    }   

}
```

error:

```
[DEBUG] [googlegauva] - Validating newly compiled units
[TRACE] [googlegauva] - Finding entry point classes
    [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Errors in 'file:/D:/arun/eclipse_Myna/GoogleGauva/src/com/arun/gauva/client/GoogleGauva.java'
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 57: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 59: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 60: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
    [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Unable to find type 'com.arun.gauva.client.GoogleGauva'
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [googlegauva] - Failed to load module 'googlegauva' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1' at 127.0.0.1:52248
[DEBUG] [googlegauva] - Validating newly compiled units
[TRACE] [googlegauva] - Finding entry point classes
    [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Errors in 'file:/D:/arun/eclipse_Myna/GoogleGauva/src/com/arun/gauva/client/GoogleGauva.java'
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 57: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 59: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Line 60: The method containsPattern(String) is undefined for the type Predicates
    [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Unable to find type 'com.arun.gauva.client.GoogleGauva'
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
        [ERROR] [googlegauva] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [googlegauva] - Failed to load module 'googlegauva' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1' at 127.0.0.1:52251
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Patterns.containsPattern`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#containsPattern%28java.lang.String%29) is annotated with `@GwtIncompatible` which means it's not in guava-gwt.

BTW, you should use the same version for guava-gwt and guava.

Comment: And it's `@GwtIncompatible` because GWT doesn't support `java.util.regex`.